# how do i move on to next page while there is no next button only numberings are available?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

how to move on to the next page as there is no next button or something like that , they providing only numberings.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time

url = 'http://dciindia.gov.in/DentistsSearch.aspx?Reg_Type=D&RegUnder=0&IDRId=&IDRName=&CourseId=0&RegDate=0&CouncilId='

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()

next_page = True
while next_page == True:
    soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table',{'id':'gvSearchDentistlist'})
    try:
        rows = table.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            if len(row.find_all('td')) == 6:
                data = row.find_all('td')
                root_url = data[5].input['onclick'].split(",")[4]
                link ='http://dciindia.gov.in/'+root_url
                print("LINK:"+link)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gvSearchDentistlist"]/tbody/tr[52]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a').click()
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        print ('No more pages')
        next_page=False

driver.close()
```

please help me anyone to crack this condition.thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `next button` your mean has unique attribute, which contains `a[href*="Page$this_is_number_of_pages"]`, one of them:

```
a[href*="Page$10"]
```

So I suggest you use `css_selector` instead of `xpath`, and use increment for each page in your loop:

```
next_page_number=2
next_page = True
while next_page == True:
    ....
    ....
    ....

    try:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[href*="Page$' +str(next_page_number) +'"]').click()
        next_page_number+=1
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        print ('No more pages')
        next_page=False
```

Or if you still want to use xpath, use the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"Page$' +str(next_page_number) +'")]').click()
```

***UPDATE**

With `for loop` it will looks as follow:

```
for next_page_number in range(2, 100+1):
    ....
    ....
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[href*="Page$' +str(next_page_number) +'"]').click()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: i want one more help, can you make code using " for loop" for next_page_number, so i can apply range.

Comment: @NiteshRao No ideas for that, because we don't know how many pages available.

Comment: can you try "for loop" for 100 pages only.

Comment: @NiteshRao See the updated answer, it looks simpler. If this is useful, don't forget to [*upvote*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow/173400#173400) the answer with click `^` icon :) Hope this helps.

Comment: @NiteshRao Welcome, glad it worked. You haven't done it yet, it's ok.